# Find out Specific No of Character in each line using Python & Storing it in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file containing many lines with many '*' I tried read(),readline(),readlines(),splitlines() at f.read() or p.splitlines() but none of them are working. Most of the time count is zero or Seven (total no of '*').

Please tell me where I am making mistake.

```
LLL*LLL*LL
AA*AAAA
NN**NNN
```

My current code

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
with open('Test.txt','r') as f:
    p = f.read()
print(p)
df12= []
 
for l in p.splitlines():
    x=p.count('*')
    df12.append(x)
print(pd.DataFrame(df12))
```

Comment: whats the goal here? you want to count the number of items in your txt file? did you try `pd.read_csv('Test.txt')` ?

Comment: I have used ',' as an example. Delimiter I have is different.

Comment: `.read_csv` has a delimiter argument `pd.read_csv(...,delimiter=';')`

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I have to do a specific split operation "re.split" based on the no of delimiter present in each line. Basically split text in each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` is probably overkill here, but if you want you can read in each line by specifying a `'\n'` as the separator then you just want to `Series.str.count` the character (need to escape with `'\*'` since `'*'` is a special character). `squeeze=True` forces it to be a Series since we know we should only have a single field.

```
s = pd.read_csv('Test.txt', header=None, sep='\n', squeeze=True)
s.str.count('\*')

0    2
1    1
2    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```